# how to create a access token in the client request and how to validate it in the lambda-authorizer code?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am new to api gateway development and trying to integrate lambda authorizer to secure the api gateway. I already gone through different documents as mentioned below, but  still didn't understand how client have bearer token generated already in the request and how lambda-authorizer validate this token?

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/python/api-gateway-authorizer-python.py
```

so far i have created the lambda-authorizer with below code found in the github and have attached the key from the autho account. Then i have attached the authorizer in the api gateway and enabled the same in the 'Method Request'.
After i deployed, i invoked the api via postman, which return: "message": "Unauthorized'

```
https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-python-auth0-custom-authorizers-api/lambda_handlers.py
```

Now i confused on what needs to be provided in the request in order to get the response from the Lambda?

Appreciate if anybody can help on this with proper example in order to integrate and test it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement JWT Token approach.You will need an authentication provider that will return you the token. Example of authentication provider is Auth0 or you can roll out your own.

The flow would be:

1. Your client will perform user authentication with this provider. The provider will return the token to your client. The client need to pass the token via Authorization header in your request payload to  API Gateway.
2. API Gateway will call Lambda Authorizer to authorize / validate the token. The Lambda Authorizer code must verify the token with the authentication provider and once authorized will return a policy that allows the API call to be made.

Comment: Hi aizul, i have updated with the question with the approach that you suggested. But i am not sure if the  above attempt actually fit  to get the right authorized response?

Comment: you need to simulate an authentication to your auth provider, get the token. Then copy the token to Authorization: Bearer <token> in postman header settings. The postman will send the api call along with the token for validation